# Multiple duplicate columns - valid normalization?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I am wondering if the following would be considered valid for 1NF/2NF/3NF.
I need to store multiple 'Location IDs' in a single table (for a linked table that needs to have multiple listed locations). After reading articles on about.com ([here](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/firstnormalform.htm)) , it appears that I cannot use duplicate columns, IE,

```
LinkedLocationID (referenced from another table)  
LocationID1 
LocationID2  
LocationID3
```

And I cannot use a non-atomic field, IE,

```
LinkedLocationID
LocationIDs
```

So, how is it possible to include three duplicative columns 'without' breaking 1NF? I require both storing multiple values for Location, and making my database 3NF-compliant.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, all four answers were pretty much saying the same thing - problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an interesection table between your two entities, like this:

```
Item
=====
ItemID
...


ItemLocation
============
ItemID
LocationID
...



Location
========
LocationID
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate table for LinkedLocationLocations with one row for each combination

So using your first example

```
LinkedLocationID | LocationIDs
1                | A,B
2                | B,C
```

becomes

```
LinkedLocationID | LocationID
1                | A
1                | B
2                | B
2                | C
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing what you are linking to, but the classic solution would be

```
Thingies
ThingyID
...

Locations
LocationID
...

ThingyLocations
ThingyID FK to Thingies
LocationID to Locations
```

Answer (score 0):

"Valid" may not be the right way to think of it. There are lots of problems and some make sense to not normalize. It matters more about how the data would be used in my opinion.

Now if normalization is your only concern, then you should not store three LocationIDs in a single table. You'd want a table linking LocationIDs to LinkedLocationID. So that table might look like:

```
LocationLinkedLocationId - LinkedLocationID - LocationID
1                          1                  1
2                          1                  2
3                          2                  1
4                          3                  1
```